# Stratified K fold same index present in both test and valid set

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation, numpy

I  am trying to do a stratified k fold cross validation for my dataset and want to keep an isolated 10% test set from the dataset and use the remaining for training and validation. Below is the code which I tried, but getting a few indexes of test index common in both train and valid set. Ideally this should not be happening as I have separated the test set in the beginning.

```
# Splitting into test and tmp set , tmp set to be further split into train and 
valid

tmp_idX, test_idX = train_test_split(idx,test_size=0.1,random_state=2) 
#idx is an array with number of files, eg for 100 files idx has elements 0-99

tmp_Y = np.asarray(grps.iloc[tmp_idX, 0])

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=1) # do 10 fold 
xval

for train_idX,valid_idX in skf.split(tmp_idX,tmp_Y): 

  #Define model and fit model
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong..

Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: Could you provide sample data? Maybe your index values are not unique?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/448360/232706, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60093361/10495893